# zeromq on M1 Mac, dyld[53597]: missing symbol called

Tags: node.js, zeromq

Did anyone managed to resolve the following error on M1 Mac, with zeromq?

dyld[53597]: missing symbol called

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** <sub>*Did anyone managed to resolve the following error on M1 Mac, with **zeromq**?*</sub>

**A :**
 No, this is most probably not the ZeroMQ error.

How can I dare say this?

Having used [zeromq](/questions/tagged/zeromq) for decade - since its c-API v2.1+ & having today v4.3.2+, there has never been any similarly sounding error-reporting feature in the core library, or its major ports (AFAIK).

### Options?

**a)**
 review the ZeroMQ language bindind used to load it into the `node.js`, chances are developers thereof could direct you to the root cause, if this was their intent to produce such an error-message

**b)**
 review the ( not published here ) wider context of the use of the code of your application, that has "delivered" your claimed error-message, as posted above. Application developers, who have designed that code, may advice you on reasons, why they've put such error-message into their code (application).

No other principal options exist.